# What are the differences between typedef and using?

Tags: c++, typedef, using

What are the differences between using

```
typedef Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName TypeName;
```

or

```
using Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName;
```

to provide the shorthand `TypeName` in the local scope?

Answer (score 6):

`typedef` gives an alias name for the type.

> typedef Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName TypeName;

Once you do that, You can refer `Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName` just by saying `TypeName` in the local namespace.

---

`using declaration` makes the type visible in the current namespace.

> using Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName;

Imports the type in the current namespace.

In this case, using the either of the above you can refer `Some::Nested::Namespace::TypeName` by just using `TypeName` in the local namespace.

Comment: Is there a real difference though? In particular in light of the boosted C++11 `using` statement which allows defining templated aliases.

Comment: There is one difference for template types at least. You can only `typedef` a specialized type, such as `vector<int>`, and you can use `using` on the unspecialized template only (`vector`, for example)

Comment: If you got a bunch of overloaded operators that you want to import, `typedef` doesn't work in this case because you have to be using `using`!

Comment: @AraK: `typedef` only works to alias **types** (as the name implies), so of course it does not work to import anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Using just brings declaration into the local scope, while typedef introduces a *typedef-name*. One difference between them is *elaborated type specifiers*, e.g.:

```
namespace n
{
  class foo
  {
  };
}

typedef n::foo n_foo;

using n::foo;

int main()
{
  class foo f1; // ok, declares f1 variable of type n::foo.
  class n_foo f2; // error, typedef-name can't be used in elaborated-type-specifier.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

They have different origins and different uses.

---

`typedef` comes from `C`: recall that the C way to declare a struct is:

```
typedef struct _MyStruct { .... } MyStruct;
```

It allows you to introduce an alias *for a type* only. It can be used for the type of a function, with an awkward syntax...

```
typedef void (*Func)(Foo, Bar);
```

Where `Func` is now a pointer to a function taking two arguments by copy (of types `Foo` and `Bar` respectively) and returning nothing.

---

`using` has, originally, a different meaning. It is meant to inject a name into a scope. Any name (nearly) can be injected: types, functions, variables (but not enum values...)

With C++11, the syntax has been enhanced to allow template aliasing:

```
template <typename T>
using equiv_map = std::map<T,T>;
```

This powered-up `using` means that aliasing (see below) is now possible, on top of the previous functionalities.

---

This C++11 change is a clear direction toward syntax harmonization. Note how the definition of an alias is now similar to the definition of a variable:

```
<name> = <expression>;
```

<strike>Unfortunately it seems the Standard reserved this aliasing to template situations, so for now both `typedef` and `using` coexist, each with its own hunting ground.</strike>

Comment: Do you mean with your last paragraph that `using name = int;` is not well-formed in C++11?

Comment: @DyP: It is what I meant, though I cannot recall why since it does work (and is very handy for function references/pointers). I wonder if I got burned by an early version of gcc/clang.