# Injecting types from nested namespaces: Typedef or using?

Tags: c++

I have a large software framework which is currently living in a common namespace. Recently, I've moved some classes into nested namespaces, but in order to preserve backwards compatibility for the time being, I need to keep the names in the global namespace. So far, I'm using `using`:

```
namespace framework {
  namespace IO {
    struct IStream;
  }
#if COMPATIBILITY
using IO::IStream;
#endif 
}
```

However, I could equally well use `typedef IO::IStream IStream;`. Is there some advantage/disadvantage of using `typedef` over `using`?

Comment: but beware of ADL with _'used'_ function overloads; using for non-types might not exactly do what you think (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between typedef and using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657710/what-are-the-differences-between-typedef-and-using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're somewhat different things: The typedef introduces a new type name `framework::IStream`, whereas the using directive only affects the name lookup inside the scope in which it appears. (This has additional effects if you were to *also* define a separate, genuine type `framework::IStream`, but since you're not doing that, this isn't an issue.)

In that sense I'd say that `using` is an implementation detail, which is preferable over a global change of semantics that would come from introducing a new type name. So if you can get away with it, use the `using` directive in those scopes where it's needed, and you can gradually migrate those to the new system.

Comment: `typedef` does not create new types. It creates aliases and compiler does not make any difference between the "source" and "destination" typed in typedef.

Comment: @n0rd: I changed it to "type name".