# C++ Using a symbol from a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am learning how the `websocketpp` header-only library works, and I was quite perplexed by the `lib::error_code` type that is sprinkled everywhere. Xcode would only reveal to me that the declaration of the type is in the `<system_error>` header, which was somewhat confusing, because I saw that `lib` is a websocketpp namespace.

Then eventually I find this in `websocketpp/common/system_error.hpp`:

```
namespace websocketpp {
namespace lib {

#ifdef _WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_SYSTEM_ERROR_
    using std::error_code;
```

This is a `using` inside of a namespace, which is not something that I understood.

What does this do? Does this simply alias `websocketpp::lib::error_code` to be `std::error_code`?

If so, why is this not delared as `typedef std::error_code error_code`? That would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(WebSocket++ library author here) `using` allows aliasing a template class into a namespace in C++98. `typedef` (pre-c++11) requires a fully specified type.

In the case of `lib::error_code` this is irrelevant because it is not a template class, but the general pattern that the namespace `websocketpp::lib` uses to alias between `boost::` and `std::` requires that it work for template classes as well (e.g. `lib::shared_ptr`). For consistencies sake, all aliases in `websocketpp::lib` use the `using` syntax rather than switching between `typedef` for non-template classes and `using` for templates.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I agree with that reasoning. (It just made it slightly harder for me to hunt down the declaration, though now that I know this, i'll know what to look for next time)

Answer (score 1):

The two are almost identical, cf. [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) with a relevant standard quote.

That said, one user found a subtle difference concerning the grammar, cf. Konstantin Oznobihin's answer in [What are the differences between typedef and using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657710/what-are-the-differences-between-typedef-and-using) (you can't use an "Elaborated type specifier" with the typedef name, but you can with a name introduced with a using declaration). Cf. par. 7.1.6.3 of the standard draft.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I tried replacing the line with a `typedef` and it seems like the code also compiles. So it has the same effect as used here.

Comment: You are right, I completely rewrote my answer. An "Elaborated type specifier" is the C way of declaring struct vars, like "struct T t;". That's usually not necessary in C++ because the class name itself is already the type name, but it's still possible (removing that would break ported C code).